# Using Isnumeric with wild card in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with  80 column. Out of which 60 columns are Numeric field. I would like to check if the column values are Number or Not i can do that by using

```
SELECT * FROM IPP where isnumeric(2009)=1
```

`2009` is column name

Is there a way i can use wild card `%200%` in isnumeric i.e.

```
isnumeric('%200%')
```

Because of i have around 60 column with year and these column are going to increase over the time

I am trying this

```
SELECT * FROM IPP where isnumeric('%2009%')=1
```

Is it possible?

Comment: No. But you can write some dynamic SQL that will do it for you. Here's a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463365/looping-through-column-names-with-dynamic-sql Start with this and post back if you get stuck.

Comment: 1. Your data model seems very bad. New data should never lead to new columns, but only to new rows. (I.e. you want to add *data* not change the *data structure*.) 2. 2009 is a bad column name. You should not use numbers as column names in order to avoid confusion and the hassle of using them. 3. If you have 60 numeric columns then the data in there *is* numeric of course; you cannot put non-numerics in a numeric column. Or are you saying you want to check for nulls? **My strong advice: change your data model. This will make things much easier for you.**

Comment: The problem is client will be giving us the file in the format where 2009 will be column, i am dynamically unpivoting them as rows in sql server. Now i want to validate the client file in sql server to check that these column should only have numeric fields.

Comment: Ah, okay. I guess I would check and probably even convert the file *before* importing it into the database.

Comment: I did that too but pivoting them in excel is taking too much time and for few tables it is exceeding the limit of excel :(

Answer (score 1):

Best you can do in one statement with using unpivot, but you still have to wrie all columns:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(id INT IDENTITY, [2008] VARCHAR(100), [2009] VARCHAR(100), [2011] VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('1.1', 'asd', '1'),
('200.1', '2', '1'),
('11', '3', 'jj')

SELECT * FROM @t
UNPIVOT(a FOR b IN([2008],[2009],[2011]))u
WHERE ISNUMERIC(a) <> 1 AND b LIKE '%200%'
```

Output:

```
id  a   b
1   asd 2009
```

Another way is to use dynamic `sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE TableTest(id INT IDENTITY, name VARCHAR(100), [2008] VARCHAR(100), [2009] VARCHAR(100), [2011] VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO TableTest VALUES
('name1', '1.1', 'asd', '1'),
('name2', '200.1', '2', '1'),
('name3', '11', '3', 'jj')

DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX) = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.name) FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE o.name = 'TableTest' AND c.name LIKE '%200%'
FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '') 


DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 
'SELECT * FROM TableTest
UNPIVOT(a FOR b IN('+@cols+'))u
WHERE ISNUMERIC(a) <> 1'

EXEC(@sql)
```

Output:

```
id  name    2011    a   b
1   name1   1       asd 2009
```