# Replicate SQL row with same data but not defining all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Is it possible to do a SQL query where I can take let's say all columns form the row for user 'A' and copy them into row for user 'B' without defining the column names.

For an Example, this will not be against speed or intense data, but to help these tasks be functional instead of doing them redundantly over and over. The params for base user and target user would be the stored procedure params.

```
Declare @BaseUserId varchar(50),
    @TargetUserId varchar(50),
    @ColumnName varchar(100)

Declare columnNameCursor Cursor For SELECT c.name
        FROM sys.columns c
        WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.EmployeeMenuAccess')

--Opens the cursor now for loop reading
Open columnNameCursor



Fetch next From columnNameCursor into @ColumnName


While @@Fetch_Status=0 Begin
  update DocSS set @ColumnName = (select @ColumnName from DocSS where 
  Username = @BaseUserId) where Username = @TargetUserID
  Fetch next From c into @ColumnName
End


Close columnNameCursor
Deallocate columnNameCursor
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you need it for inserting or updating?

Comment: The reason I am asking this is because we replicate a lot of users, but not enough users have a set uniform setup for us to create a batch script or procedure to hand this easily. There are also other tables we do this for that have many columns of all bit switches. So i am finding a way to make this easier, and less prone to missing one bi switch when trying to compare them, but also to make it a function we can just call like we do with many other scripts.

Comment: updating, and possibly  inserting. Only need to focus on updating at the moment because this is done after the fields are entered by default during account setups, so 99% of the time it will be an update.

Comment: And I am a web full stack developer, is not SQL Guru. So I do apologize if this is not possible. -Thanks-

Comment: I do not think it is possible, at least in sql server, and seems you are doing the update based on 1 user, why not just delete and insert?

Comment: I kind of see somthing similiar found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463365/looping-through-column-names-with-dynamic-sql

Comment: Seems like a simple `INSERT INTO SELECT` to me, the way you have defined the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Test
    (id int, name char(10))
;
INSERT INTO Test VALUES(1, 'first');
INSERT INTO Test VALUES(2, 'second');
BEGIN TRAN T1;
SELECT * INTO Temp FROM Test WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE Temp SET id = (SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM Test);
INSERT INTO Test SELECT * FROM Temp;
DROP TABLE Temp;
COMMIT TRAN T1;
SELECT * FROM Test;
```

Try [this](http://rextester.com/FHBG34025)

Comment: What if I do not want to use a new key, but just replicate data into an already existing row, but keep the keys? Or is the best to remove the row and do an insert?

Comment: I see the way you are thinking of doing it. I like this. Perfect and exactly what I needed. As I mentioned I am a full stack developer, but not awesome with SQL. So I like this response, and thank you for it.