# Count distinct values for every column individually

Tags: sql, oracle, count, distinct

Can I count distinct values of every column without enumerating them ?

Say I have a table with `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, and no other column. Without mentioning these columns explicitly, I would like to have the same result as:

```
SELECT
count(distinct col1) as col1,
count(distinct col2) as col2,
count(distinct col3) as col3
FROM mytable;
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20463450/2923617

Comment: Would a plsql script generating dynamic query be ok, or do you need your answer in pure sql?

Comment: Pure `SQL` would be better, as I'm sending these queries through `R` ad I don't know a way to send `PL SQL` from R to Oracle.

Comment: _Columns_, not fields...

Comment: sorry, corrected :)

Comment: Looks much better now!

Comment: Basically, you can't do this in raw SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best you could easily do with plain SQL is to run a query like this to generate the query you want, and then run that.

```
select 'select count(distinct '
    || listagg(column_name || ') as ' || column_name, ', count(distinct ') within group (order by column_id) 
    || ' from ' || max(table_name) || ';' as script
from all_tab_cols
where table_name = 'MYTABLE';
```

Comment: It's a good idea, a first query will fetch the text, and a second one will feed it back to the db as a query.