# Is there a way to apply plyr's count() function to every column individually?

Tags: r

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754990/count-distinct-values-for-every-column-individually) but for R. I want to get a summary count of every variable in each column of a data frame.

Currently, doing something like plyr::count(df[,1:10]) checks for how many times every variable in a row match. Instead, I just want a quick way of printing out what all my variables even are, though. I know this can be done with C-style recursion, but I'm hoping for a more elegant/simpler solution.

Comment: I think simply `lapply(df, plyr::count)` should give what you want

Comment: Shoot, I was so close with apply(mtcars, 1:10, plyr::count). Oops! Thanks! Answer it and the vote/solved is all yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lapply`:

```
lapply(df, plyr::count)
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, keeping everything in base R you can use `table` with `stack` to get similar output

```
lapply(df, function(x) stack(table(x)))
```

Comment: Ah, nice one. Thanks for the addition!