# Is there any way to iterate through each column in a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 10 columns.What i need is to select each column through while loop(select each column name not each column values) and find if its name ends with 'box' if it is yes then add that column value to a variable.

For eg:

```
while(column_name(1) = like'%box')
    begin
    select @value = column_name  from table 
    select column_name = column_name + 1 (i.e select next column name from table)
    end
```

Comment: query `sys.columns` or `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to get the column name

Comment: Yes there is. I'm suprised I couldn't find a good explanation on SO. Here's something simliar (it's more than what you need) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463365/looping-through-column-names-with-dynamic-sql

Comment: I tried this bro but couldnt alter it to my way. @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Usually a sign of a broken data model if you have multiple columns containing the same "type" of data such that you want to query over all of them uniformly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not done with a while loop but a quick and easy way to find any column where the name like.

```
SELECT   
        c.name  AS 'ColumnName'
        ,t.name AS 'TableName'
FROM        
        sys.columns c
JOIN        
        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE      
        t.name = 'TableName'
        AND c.name LIKE 'box%'
ORDER BY    
         TableName
        ,ColumnName;
```

Answer updated to now include the table name in the where clause.

Comment: it searches my whole database but i need is to search only one table.