# MS Access: How to find greatest length of all fields?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working to move an Access database into SQL Server. For this, I need to know how long to make the VARCHAR fields.

Is there a query I can use within Access to return the longest length of a value for each column?

I have found several options using the more advanced T-SQL of SQL Server, but cannot find any way to do this with Access. Since the database has almost 200 columns, I'd prefer to not have to do this with 200 manual queries.

Comment: Why not just use 8000 or max?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Our IT department requires we set length limits for the fields.

Comment: If you are using SSMS, you cam use "suggest" option to identify type and length of field. You can also use the functions MAX and LEN in sql to retreive the maximum value.

Comment: @Zayfaya83 - Unfortunately, IT is only given test data; they only have to build the tables and we will populate with true data.

Comment: I would suggest some combination of MAX(LEN(column_name)), applied on all columns. Here an idea how to loop on all columns:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463365/looping-through-column-names-with-dynamic-sql

Comment: Using the maximum length of current data as the basis for the size of new fields is probably a bad idea. You should be considering what the maximum length that could be stored in each field, and then adding a fair bit of extra room just in case. Otherwise, when the database is all up and running, data gets added that is too long to be stored, and you will need to do some very fast database changes.....

Comment: @Applecore - I agree. Unfortunately, I am limited by what my IT department will allow. I'm only a lowly developer and don't get to make the final decisions.

Answer (score 0):

Opss.... sorry, Try this Sub , hope it will help you more.

```
Sub getFieldSize()
Const SQL As String = "SELECT Max(Len([{fld_len}])) AS Expr1 FROM {tbl}"

    Const constPad01 = 25
    Const constPad03 = 45
    Dim db As DAO.Database, tbl As DAO.TableDef, fld As DAO.Field, rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sStmt As String, strSchema As String, strSQL As String
    Dim X As Long
    Set db = CurrentDb
    strSchema = "****  " & CurrentDb.Name & "  ****" & vbNewLine
    For Each tbl In db.TableDefs
        If Left(tbl.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
            strSchema = strSchema & "===================================" & vbNewLine & vbTab & tbl.Name & vbNewLine
            For Each fld In tbl.Fields
                If Len(fld.Name) > 25 Then
                    sStmt = " " & fld.Name & String(constPad03 - Len(fld.Name), " ")
                Else
                    sStmt = " " & fld.Name & String(constPad01 - Len(fld.Name), " ")
                End If
                Select Case fld.Type
                    Case dbText:
                        strSQL = Replace(SQL, "{fld_len}", fld.Name)
                        strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "{tbl}", tbl.Name)
                        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
                        If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then X = rs!Expr1
                        Set rs = Nothing
                        sStmt = sStmt & "text length " & " (" & X & ")"
                        X = 0
                    Case dbMemo:
                        strSQL = Replace(SQL, "{fld_len}", fld.Name)
                        strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "{tbl}", tbl.Name)
                        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
                        If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then X = rs!Expr1
                        Set rs = Nothing
                        sStmt = sStmt & "memo length" & " (" & X & ")"
                        X = 0
                    Case Else:
                        sStmt = ""
                End Select
               If sStmt <> "" Then strSchema = strSchema & sStmt & vbNewLine
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Debug.Print strSchema
    Set db = Nothing
    Open CurrentProject.Path & "\Schema.txt" For Output As #1: Print #1, strSchema: Close #1

End Sub
```

Comment: The OP just needs the length of the varchar fields.

Comment: This gives me the DEFINED field length, but not the length of the longest value.

Comment: tell your IT department to do for all variables NVARCHAR(2000), then you have the data and make a new table by yourself or do some more tests. If 2000 is not enough, make 3000. Maybe this is a practicle solution. Just like Gordon Linoff mentioned.

Comment: how many rows do you have? You can also load it in excel and get the max length with easy formula, should be done in a few minutes.

Comment: Whats wrong with using the defined length?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
Max(Len([Fieldname1])) AS Expr1, 
Max(Len([Fieldname2])) AS Expr2,  
Max(Len([Fieldname3])) AS Expr3 
FROM Tablename;
```

This will show you the max length of each field in the table.