# Get contents of the whole column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to retrieve the contents of an entire column. Select in brackets gets me the correct column names. The result returns instead of data the column name as many times as there are rows with data in the table (instead of data).

```
WHILE @cnt < @column_count
BEGIN
    SELECT (
        SELECT *
        FROM #TEMP_COLUMN_NAME
        ORDER BY (SELECT null)
        OFFSET @CNT ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
    ) FROM DDServices_History;

    SET @CNT = @CNT + 1;
END;
```

I receive something like this:

[image]

And I would like to get the data from these tables and not the column names.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Comment: 1) [edit] any clarifications directly into your question. 2) Please show formatted text, not images.

Comment: You can't dynamically select a column using SQL, you are going to need dynamic SQL for what you are asking.

Comment: do you simply want to iterate on the sql results ? its hard to undestand what you want to do like this ...

Comment: `ORDER BY (SELECT null)` And that is logical nonsense.

Comment: I want, for each column, to iterate through its rows to then compare them to each other and capture changes,

Comment: You're looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463365/looping-through-column-names-with-dynamic-sql). I suggest doing some research along the lines of "sql SERVER iterate over all columns" and then asking a new question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL.  Something like this:

```
DECLARE  @SqlStatement AS NVARCHAR(1000);
```

Then within your loop:

```
SET @SqlStatement = 'SELECT ' + (
        SELECT *
        FROM #TEMP_COLUMN_NAME
        ORDER BY 1
        OFFSET @CNT ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
    ) + ' FROM DDServices_History';
    
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SqlStatement;
```